# APi $HTTP Para Requisições em Banco De Dados MySQL

Tags: angularjs, http-request

Galera eu vejo em cursos e video aulas o pessoal ultilizando essa `$http` na hora de fazer requisições com o AngularJS, só que eles sempre passam uma url amigavel na hora de fazer a conexão e eu não sei como eles fazem isso porque tipo eles não passam nem usuario, nem senha, nada, e mesmo assim conseguem fazer a conexão e eu fico meio sem entender e não consigo prosseguir com o curso com ou com o tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS é executado no lado do cliente é feito um request para uma URL, essa URL deve ser provida por um servidor de aplicação APACHE,NODEJS entre outros. Os tutorias que você deve está seguindo, devem abstrair a logica do servidor onde lá é feita a conexão com o banco de dados, a consulta e os tratamentos.

Sugiro que você veja os videos do  [Rodrigo Branas](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLQCmSnNFVYnTD5p2fR4EXmtlR6jQJMbPb) ele tem um vídeo sobre integração com o backend.

Comment: Eu tava assistindo era justamente os videos dele e ai do nada ele me veio com a seguinte URL "localhost:3412/contatos" e usando só essa URL ele conseguiu fazer get, post, put, delete, fez tudo....

Comment: Ele está usando o NodeJS, siga na ordem os videos dele que vc vai entender, as vezes ele só demonstra alguma função, mas tem outros videos explicando sobre o NodeJS.

Comment: Sabe alguma API para fazer isso com o mysql?